# How to set a WCF URL from WebConfig

Tags: c#, wcf

I am working on a website that uses a WCF. The thing I want to do is that whenever the WebService URL is changed, i must be able to change in My project without having to stop this. So i thought of setting a key in webconfig of my project and to set that key value as URI in Reference.cs. I changed the state of WebService Reference in my project as dynamic. But the problem is that whenever I update the webservice, the uri gets changed to the text shown below :

"`global::Drd.Properties.Settings.Default.CoreBusiness_UbossProvisioning_ProvisioningServices;`".

What am i missing here?? Can anyone please help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of your Service Client or you Service and you can provide the URL to the constructor. That might be easier.

Comment: Am new to this so could you please break it down to me.. THis is the constructor ` string url = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UbossBridgeURL"];
            if ((this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(this.Url) == true))
            {
                this.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = false;
            }
            else
            {
                this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = true;
            }`

Answer (score 0):

> What am i missing here??

You can set the URL in your config and when you are going to create a new instance of that service you can set the endpoint address like this

```
YouService.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress("Address from your config.");
```

Comment: In the constructor there is a section where we specify URl.. I set the config value there and it worked but when you update the web service , it gets to the default value i specified above... The think is am not able to identify where that this.Url goes and how it connnects to WebService . :'(

Answer (score 0):

When you set the URL Behavior to *Dynamic*, the framework does everything for you:

- Adds a key to the `web.config` file (look for `CoreBusiness_UbossProvisioning_ProvisioningServices`)
- Generate `Reference.cs` so it would read the settings from the configuration.

If you added the reference to another assembly, copy the following sections from its `app.config` to your `web.config` (you may need to correct your namespaces, I'm just guessing yours):

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
        <section name="Drd.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

And

```
<applicationSettings>
    <Drd.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="CoreBusiness_UbossProvisioning_ProvisioningServices"
            serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://yourservice/address</value>
        </setting>
    </Drd.Properties.Settings>
</applicationSettings>
```

(Also, as a general rule, never edit generated files.)

**Alternative Option**

If you want to use your `UbossBridgeURL` in `AppSettings`, you can create a derived client class and set its URL in the constructor (I'm assuming the generated class is class `ProvisioningServices`):

```
public class MyProvisioningServices : ProvisioningServices
{
     public MyProvisioningServices()
     {
         Url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UbossBridgeURL"];
     }
}
```

Then use the `MyProvisioningServices` class instead of `ProvisioningServices`.

Comment: yes that the thing i have.. ` public ProvisioningServices()
        {
            this.Url = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UbossBridgeURL"];            if ((this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(this.Url) == true))            {
                this.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = false;
            }
            else
            {
                this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = true;
            }
        }` .But what if i have to update the webrefrerence? It regenrate ref.cs gets updated

Comment: Is there any other way i can achieve this dynamic url, because whenever we write a new method in web service  we have to update the reference and whenever we update the ref, ref.cs gets written again and we loose the key value

Comment: UbossBridgeURL  key is in web config not app config. The Webservice Reference lies in a project which's ddl in put in main project. So i added the UbossBridgeURL  key in the main project's webconfig

Comment: Do i have to copy both these sections from my app config to my web config and keep reference.cs intact? is that what you mean?

Comment: what exactly do these two settings do and where exactly in web config shall i put this

Comment: what is settings.settings file. in it i saw this code `    <Setting Name="CoreBusiness_UbossProvisioning_ProvisioningServices" Type="(Web Service URL)" Scope="Application">
      <Value Profile="(Default)">http://drdindia-db-dev:8080/Service.svc</Value>
    </Setting>`

Comment: I found out a thing.There is a settings.setting file and it contains the webservice corresponding details. In web reference properties there is a url and the settings.settings page sets it as default value and its from there the global::Drd.Properties.Settings.Default.CoreBusiness_UbossBridge_ActionBase; takes the value. So how can i over ride it